# Samsung s duos not booting into recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have flashed the recovery.tar using odin by following this tutorial http://www.droidiser.com/2012/10/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-s-duos-install-cwm.html

but after this,when I try to boot into recovery mode by pressing `volume up+volume down+home+power` key simultaneously,it shows samsung logo followed by cwm recovery icon but then it just goes off and boots up normally.

what am I doing wrong ? please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to release the buttons just after samsung logo and not after seeing cwm screen

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need more tries to go back into recovery. If it does not work, you might have to re-flash the proper .tar file with Odin.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the latest Samsung devices do not boot into recovery on a phone reboot. The device needs to be shut down before.
You need to hold Volume Up + Menu Buttons for a few seconds. The power button only triggers the phone startup, do not hold it.